# Display a custom attribute below product name in the front-end Magento 1.9.3.8

Tags: php, attributes, magento-1, product-view

I need to display a custom attribute bellow the product name and I don't know how can I call this attribute.

I am editing the file `/app/design/frontend/templatemela/MAG100219_1/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`
But how can I call this attribute in php? I tried calling a string echo with the name I put in the attribute, but it didn't work.

Code is as below:

```
<div class="page-title product-title"> 
<h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
</div>

<div class="codigoinmetro"> 
<h2><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'registroinmetro') ?></h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Which type of attribute you have text or dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
 <div class="page-title product-title"> 
 <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
 </div>

 <div class="codigoinmetro"> 
 <h2><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getRegistroinmetro(), 'registroinmetro') ?></h2>
 </div>
```

Comment: what this $_helper point to ?

Comment: Its points to product module (Magento core Module For Product) helper. If you open that helper file you will see "productAttribute" function.

Comment: @Sourav , $_helper in my code is the correction of the question's code.

Comment: @EmanuellVieira , had your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code i'm using this code. this code working fine. replace your attribute name with (Brand)

```
<?php
$brandname = $_product->getAttributeText('brand');
    if (trim($brandname)) {
        echo "" .$this->htmlEscape($brandname);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have select type attribute then you can use below code to get attribute value:


```
$attributeName = $product->getAttributeText('attributename');
```


If you have input type attribute then you can use below:


```
$attributeName = $product->getAttributeName ();
```